# <strong> tag not showing up in Chrome but does show up in all other browsers

Tags: css, google-chrome

I am working for a client and have updated her site with a new font.  The problem is the  tag is working for all browsers except Chrome.

Any ideas why this might be happening?  Site is http://passionatepennypincher.com.

I have researched it and tried several things, i.e., `strong {font-weight: bold;}` but this does not work.  I would be grateful for any help.  Thank you!

Comment: please post an example on jsfiddle.net/

Comment: The content inside the strong-tags is bold in Chrome 26.0.1410.64.

Comment: Just to note, if it doesn't show up it's fine to use CSS `font-weight:bold;` because the ideology behind the tag is to use it for semantic purposes, not styling.

Answer (score 5):

It is working (checked in Chrome on OSX).

Looks like you're using font replacement with a typeface that doesn't respond especially well to having a bold style applied to it.

To double check bold is definitely working, swap out the Inder font for a web-safe alternative (e.g. Arial), if the bold is more prominent/visible using Arial, you know it's just the Inder font.

S

Comment: I am using Lion, maybe that is why I am not seeing it.  I will use a better font yes ... the css is all messed up ... inherited the problem.  Thank you all so much!!

Answer (score 0):

I've just had a look at the site in Chrome and the text in  tags is showing up for me.

The text on the homepage is 'Here are the top retail coupons available this week, thanks to Your Retail Helper! ' and I can see the  tags in the source and the text is showing in  a bold weight.

```
<p><strong>Here are the top retail coupons available this week, thanks to Your Retail Helper!</strong> Check out my favorites below, but be sure to visit <a href="http://yourretailhelper.blogspot.com/" target="_blank">Your Retail Helper</a> for the complete list of deals:</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

I met the same problem in my chrome. I think it is a problem of font. So i  change my standard font("STHeiti") to try to improve my guess. I found when i change the font to the font-family which is without "heiti" in its names, <strong> was working. And i also change my other browser's standard font to the font family which named like "*xx*heiti" and "heiti*xx*", then <strong> was working no longer.
So, i found the "heiti" font family(e.g. STheiti, Heiti SC, Heiti TC etc.) is the “criminal” of this problem, <strong> is not effective in the "heiti" font. The "heiti" is chinese pronunciation of “bold”.
In other words <strong> tag is not working in the browser which standard font is set to any "heiti" because those font families already have the meaning of "bold". It is the ultimate reason why <strong> was not showing up in your chrome.